# Validating angular2 control on blur or any other event

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am working on validating forms in Angular2, I used default validators and some custom validation functions to validate. Also I implemented async validation from server. Now the problem is, It is validating control on change event and executing ajax request every keypress on that control. I am expecting to execute that ajax request to be execute on blur of that control.

Is there any way to control validation of that control? or execute validation on blur or any other event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to manually control the validation, you could use `setErrors` of class `AbstractControl` (I am assuming you are using model-driven or having reference of the FormControl in your component).

So, don't hard-coding the Validator function to your form initiation

```
this.userNameFormControl = this.formBuilder.control(""/*, Validators.required*/);
```

Instead, subscribe to your custom event and validate the control manually:

```
validateUserName() {
  let validationResult = Validators.required(this.userNameFormControl);
  if (validationResult) {
    this.userNameFormControl.setErrors(validationResult);
  }
}
```

Note: These code lines were not tested.

Comment: This is not a good idea I believe. Because in my application I need to validate all the fields on blur. So writing the validation for each field like that is complex and not good practice I believe. Looking for some other answers.